# How to make flutter android app compatible with samsung j6 and j4?

Tags: android, flutter, version, compatibility, galaxy

I'm currently working on a flutter app with flutter version 1.17.5 on stable channel. It works perfectly well on most android phones, but with Samsung Galaxy J6 and J4, the app simply is not able to open. It just crashes.
The android version on the phone is 10 (29 api) and my minSdkVersion is 21 and the targetSdkVersion is 28

I have been reading about this issue and some advice is to downgrade to the flutter version 1.10.9, but if I do that, there are conflicts with my plugins I'm using, so that is not an option.

I know it's a plugin issue, since i made a new app without any plugin (just a create app command) and it works perfectly well

These are the plugins i'm using:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  path_provider:
  location: ^3.0.2  
  path:
  #gallery_saver: 1.0.7
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+4
  google_maps_flutter: 
  #downloads_path_provider: 0.1.0
  geolocator: ^5.3.1
  #new_geolocation: 1.0.0
  font_awesome_flutter:
  #image_downloader: 0.19.2
  page_transition:
  video_player: ^0.10.11
  flutter_bloc: ^4.0.0
  #video_player_header:
  flutter_youtube:
  animator:
  rename: ^1.2.0
  datetime_picker_formfield: 
  onesignal_flutter: ^2.6.0
  flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle: ^1.0.7
  flutter_datetime_picker:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/derohimat/flutter_datetime_picker.git
  #camera: ^0.5.8+1
  fluttertoast: ^4.0.1
  after_layout:
  material_design_icons_flutter:
  dart_rut_validator: ^1.0.0
  flutter_sound: 3.0.0
  states_rebuilder:
  http:
  webview_flutter:
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.7
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: 0.3.0
  rxdart: ^0.18.0
  analyzer: ^0.38.4
  build_resolvers:
  #flutter_advanced_networkimage:
  dio: #^3.0.9
  http_auth:
  retry: ^3.0.0+1
  connectivity: 
  showcaseview: ^0.1.5
  inject:
    path: ./injection/inject.dart/package/inject  


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.5
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  inject_generator:
    path: ./injection/inject.dart/package/inject_generator
```

I have the bad luck that my client's phone is a J6, so he can't actually run the app.
How can it be that flutter doesn't offer a solution?
Does anyone have similar problems or a solution?

Comment: It may depend on what android version your client is using. Make sure that you target that version at the minimum. See your android\app\build.gradle file to check what version you're targeting. Check this resource for what Flutter officially supports. https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#what-devices-and-os-versions-does-flutter-run-on

Comment: any error or hints for debugging?

Comment: @James The phone has android 10 (API 29), and my minsdk version is 21 and target 28, so that should not be an issue.

Comment: @Doc no, it just doesn't open. No error or log, it just tries to open, but before showing the splash screen it just crashes

Answer (score 0):

I noticed Samsung J6 and J4 doesn’t work with Wi-Fi with Flutter.
If the Wi-Fi is off it will work.
Try to check the connection and change the network.